# Is it possible to login into lightdm interactive screen remotely?

Tags: ssh, lightdm, login-screen

I have this big Ubuntu desktop that dubs also as a home cinema PC.

When I feel lazy, I'd love to be able to run the PC remotely and watch movies from my bed. I can turn it on via WoL. I can launch remote applications remotely via ssh by modification to `DISPLAY` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variables.

The last obstacle is to bypass the login screen presented by (`lightdm`).

I don't want to turn on automatic logging in for security reasons.

I am *not* interested in forwarding remote windows locally à la VNC.

Comment: dont know if ssh -X will help